# QEMU - supported machine no longer present

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, rhel

I am porting over some code/scripts that was using `QEMU 0.12` to latest `QEMU 2.8`. In the older `QEMU` a machine type of `rhel6.3.0` was used.
In the newer `QEMU`, that machine type is not available. I can't find how these machines types are added/removed into `QEMU`. Is there a way for me to get the same `rhel6.3.0` machine type in the newer `QEMU` ??

Thx

Comment: You've tagged your question `vms`, but I don't see a relation to the VMS family of operating systems. Did you assume that it had something to do with virtual machines (VMs)?

Comment: @HABO - yes i am sorry for incorrectly tagging as vms..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests, 'rhel6.3.0' is a machine specific to Red Hat's packaging of QEMU, so it doesn't and never has existed in upstream QEMU. So I would suggest first checking whether Red Hat's new QEMU packages still have 'rhel6.3.0' in them. Red Hat may also have documentation about how to migrate forward from older versions.

Failing that, don't try to add support for it to the new QEMU, because that will be a huge pain, because the point of the machine name is to say "this precisely emulates the level of hardware support, bugs, etc which were in that old version of QEMU", and identifying exactly what needs to be set up in what way for that old machine type will require a lot of software archaeology.

Instead, just use a newer machine type to run your VMs. (I assume you're not trying to live-migrate from your ancient QEMU to a new one; that's pretty unlikely to work across that large a span of versions.)